# How do I make rows use the rowid of a deleted row with a lower rowid than them?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How do I make sure that deleted rowids are replaced by the rowids that succeed them? Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    test_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    test_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_table (test_name)
VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

DELETE FROM test_table WHERE test_name = 'C';
```

Now the results are:

| test_id | test_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

How do I make the rows following the deleted row cover up the unused rowid before them? Something like this:

| test_id | test_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | E |
| 5 | F |

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Why would having gaps there be an issue? Changing id's overtime for the same record is usually a very bad idea. (while reusing old unused id's is sometimes an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this.  First, `rowid` is an *internal* identifier for the row in the table.  It is surfaced to users, but its purpose is to provide a unique identifier -- not a gapless number.

Second, if you want a gapless number, just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by test_id) as gapless_test_id
from test_table t;
```

Why is changing the id on a bunch of rows a bad idea?  The `rowid` column is typically the primary key in a table where it is defined.  The primary key should be stable.  It might be used for foreign key references in other tables.  You don't want to have to change all tables in your database just because you deleted a row in one central table.

In addition, primary keys should be stable *over time*.  If you note that `test_id = 3` has some particular property, you want "3" to reference the same row tomorrow.